# Custom login in laravel with single table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

As i searched a lot to create the custom multi auth in laravel on single table for different different user (i.e Customer,Shopkeeper,Admin,Delivery Executives). and this is done on single table i.e. user_table which contain a column name user_type which will hold that what type of user is that, as i need to do like this because existing system was developed in PHP and having same schema but i want to upgrade to laravel so i stuck up in the very first step.

But i searched then found to create multiple tables like admin,customer and etc but for this i have to alter my current database which i dont need.

So, any one help me out how to do it exactly.

Comment: Have you created a model for your `user_table`?

Comment: yes @RossWilson i have created the model
  user_type is required 'admin', 'user', 'dataoperator', 'deliveryboy','shopkeeper'

Comment: Would using middleware to prevent certain users from hitting different routes not work? Or even using something like `Policies`?

Comment: so can u show me some demo or snippet which is done on the logic.. because i tried to find this but not able to get that..

Comment: Can you give me an example of why you need to have the different logins?

Comment: Yes like this is a multi user website, when general customer will login then they will get the relevant routes and when admin login to system then they redirect to admin panel which will get the other routes and when shopkeeper login then they get the seperate routes and same for the delivery boys and dataoperators

Comment: Hi shubham could you post your database schema here please

Comment: sure,
`user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'user_id common to all',
  `user_fullname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `user_contact` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `user_auth_id` varchar(550) NOT NULL,
  `user_auth_provider` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `user_status` enum('0','1') NOT NULL COMMENT '0 for un active ,1 for active',
  `regdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  `user_type` enum('admin','user','dataoperator','deliveryboy') NOT NULL